# Unable to scrape the conversation among debaters in order to put them in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script to fetch all the conversation between different debaters ***`excluding moderators`***. What I've written so far can fetch the total conversation. However, I would like to grab them like `{speaker_name: (first speech, second speech) etc }`.

[Webpage link](https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/presidential-debate-the-university-nevada-las-vegas)

another one similar to the above link

[webpage link](https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/republican-presidential-candidates-debate-manchester-new-hampshire-0)

I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/presidential-debate-the-university-nevada-las-vegas'

def get_links(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".field-docs-content p:has( > strong:contains('MODERATOR:')) ~ p"):
        print(item.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links(url)
```

How can I scrape the conversation among debaters and put them in a dictionary?

Comment: Could you please share an expected output from the real data ?

Comment: Are you looking for the key to be the speaker name and the value is a list of all the things they said? for example: `{ 'Brown': ['Good evening', 'how are you']}`

Comment: Okay, I've edited the question to clarify what the expected output might look like. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't hold much hope for this lasting across lots of pages given the variability amongst the two pages I saw and the number of assumptions I have had to make. Essentially, I use regex on participant and moderators nodes text to isolate the lists of moderators and participants. I then loop all speech paragraphs and each time I encounter a moderator at the start of a paragraph I set a boolean variable `store_paragraph = False` and ignore subsequent paragraphs; likewise, each time I encounter a participant, I set  `store_paragraph = True` and store that paragraph and subsequent ones under the appropriate participant key in my `speaker_dict`. I store each `speaker_dict` in a final `results` dictionary.

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pprint

links = ['https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/presidential-debate-the-university-nevada-las-vegas','https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/republican-presidential-candidates-debate-manchester-new-hampshire-0']
results = {}
p = re.compile(r'\b(\w+)\b\s+\(|\b(\w+)\b,')

with requests.Session() as s:
    for number, link in enumerate(links):
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
        participants_tag = soup.select_one('p:has(strong:contains("PARTICIPANTS:"))')

        if participants_tag.select_one('strong'):
            participants_tag.strong.decompose()
        speaker_dict = {i[0].upper() + ':' if i[0] else i[1].upper() + ':': [] for string in participants_tag.stripped_strings for i in p.findall(string)}
        # print(speaker_dict)
        moderator_data = [string for string in soup.select_one('p:has(strong:contains("MODERATOR:","MODERATORS:"))').stripped_strings][1:]
        #print(moderator_data)
        moderators = [i[0].upper() + ':' if i[0] else i[1].upper() + ':' for string in moderator_data for i in p.findall(string)]
        store_paragraph = False

        for paragraph in soup.select('.field-docs-content p:not(p:contains("PARTICIPANTS:","MODERATOR:"))')[1:]:
            string_to_compare = paragraph.text.split(':')[0] + ':'
            string_to_compare = string_to_compare.upper()
            if string_to_compare in moderators:
                store_paragraph = False
            elif string_to_compare in speaker_dict:
                speaker = string_to_compare
                store_paragraph = True
            if store_paragraph:
                speaker_dict[speaker].append(paragraph.text)
        results[number] = speaker_dict

pprint.pprint(results[1])
```

Comment: How could I miss this answer? I'll let you know once I'm done testing it. thanks for your time @QHarr.